# A gap occurs between a node and a line starting from it although "inner sep" and "outer sep" are set to 0pt

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (10,10);
\draw[very thick,rotate around={45:(2.3,5)}] (2.3,5) rectangle ++(4,0.3) ++(0,-0.15) node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (p2) {};
\draw[very thick,rotate around={-10:($(2.3,5)+(45:4)$)}] (2.3,5)++(45:4) rectangle ++(4,0.3)--++(0,0.2)--++(0.7,0)--++(0,-0.15)--++(-0.55,0)--++(0,-0.4)--++(0.55,0)--++(0,-0.15)--++(-0.7,0)--++(0,0.2)++(-4,0)++(0,0.15) coordinate (p3);
\draw[name path=2nd2] (p2)--+(45:2);
\draw[name path=3rd] (p3)--+(170:2);
\path[name intersections={of=2nd2 and 3rd,by=i23}];
\fill[red] (i23) circle (0.5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:
[image]

When I zoom in, I notice that, in contrast to `(p3)` with `coordinate`, there is a distance between `(p2)` with `node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]` and the line starting from `(p2)`. Could anyone explain what causes the gap? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your empty node is still not completely empty, even when `inner sep` and `outer sep` are both set to `0pt` it has a space. A coordinate on the other hand is just a point in your coordinate system. To get the same behaviour with a node you need to set also `minimum size=0pt`. Compare the three nodes and the coordinate in the example below.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[gray!40] (0,0) grid (4,3);
  \node[label=below:np] (np) at (1,2){};
  \node[label=below:np2,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (np2) at (2,2){};
  \node[label=below:np3,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,minimum size=0pt] (np3) at (1,1){};
  \coordinate[label=below:cp] (cp) at (2,1);
  \foreach \angle in {0,45,...,315}{
    \draw[very thin,red] (np.\angle) circle (0.2pt);
    \draw[very thin,red] (np2.\angle) circle (0.2pt);
    \draw[very thin,red] (np3.\angle) circle (0.2pt);
    \draw[very thin,red] (cp.\angle) circle (0.2pt);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

On the upper left there is a normal node, on the upper right a node with inner and outer sep set to zero, on the lower left an empty node with `minimum size` set to zero and on the lower right a coordinate, all four with small circles at all directions (45 degree separation).

In your example that means when drawing from node `(p2)` towards 45 degrees it starts at `(p2.45)`, which will give you the small gap. Try changing to

```
\draw[name path=2nd2] (p2.center)--+(45:2);
```

or change `(p2)` to be a `coordinate`, or add `minimum size=0pt`.